# How do a restore/install chai typings defined as devDependencies

Tags: typescript, chai

Installed chai typings via the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) tool with the following command but now I'm unable to get typings to install chai on the build server.

```
typings install chai --save-dev
```

My `devDependencies` in *typings.json* file looks like this.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "registry:npm/chai#3.5.0+20160415060238"
}
```

On my build server I run the following command but it gives me no output indicating that the newly added typings dependency was installed.

```
sudo node ./node_modules/typings install
```

Building my project using the *tsc* TypeScript compiler now gives me the following error.

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

Looking under `typings/main/definitions/` I do not see the expected `chai` sub directory.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug in non-ambient devDependencies?

Answer (score 2):

the typings tool may not be running if you don't see any output. the best way to reference the typings tool (in a node.js context) is to add a line to your `package.json` file like:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-react-webpack",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "typings": "typings install"
  },
  ...
}
```

so that it will use nodes built in dependency lookup mechanism to find the correct file to execute. Executing `npm run typings` will then run the typings tool.

Comment: Ah, I was attempting this but forgot to omit **node** from the beginning of the command. I'll try this out and if possible I'll switch to your answer as the accepted answer if all goes well.

Comment: One concern is whether globally or locally installed dependencies have precedence. I would prefer local dependencies to override any globally installed ones. Looking around the NPM documentation I haven't found a clear answer on this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this behavior has seemed to change from before but it looks like the issue may have been in the way that I was invoking the **typings** tool.

Instead of:

```
sudo node ./node_modules/typings install
```

Should have been:

```
sudo node ./node_modules/typings/dist/bin.js install
```

Perhaps there has been a change in how the typings tool exposes things to to npm?